# C# Temperature Conversion (1 issue)

Tags: c#

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConTempConversion_Michelle
 {
    class Program
    {
       static void GetChoice(ref int ichoice)
       {
            Console.Write("Enter choice: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();// get string from the user

              bool result = int.TryParse(input, out ichoice);//convert input from     string to ichoice int value

          if (!result)
          {
             while (!result && ichoice > 3)
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid value.Try again:");

                input = Console.ReadLine();

                result = int.TryParse(input, out ichoice);
             }
          }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double fTemp;
        double cTemp;
        double convertToC;
        double convertToF;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
        Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Exit");

        int ichoice = 0;
        GetChoice(ref ichoice);
        do
        {

            if (ichoice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Fahrenheit temperature: ");
                fTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                convertToC = ConvertCelcius(fTemp);
                Console.WriteLine(fTemp + "Fahrenheit is " + convertToC + "Celsius");
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
                Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________");
                GetChoice(ref ichoice);
            }
            if (ichoice == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Celsius temperature: ");
                cTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                convertToF = ConvertCelcius(cTemp);
                Console.WriteLine(cTemp + "Celsius is " + convertToF+ "Fahrenheit");
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
                   Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________");
                GetChoice(ref ichoice);

            }
            if (ichoice == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using the temperature conversion application. Please come again.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Please choose again!");
            }

        }
        while (ichoice < 3);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    static double ConvertCelcius(double c)
    {
        double f;

        return f = 9.0 / 5.0*c + 32;
    }
    static double ConvertFahrenheit(double f)
    {
        double c;

        return c = (f  -  32)  *  (5.0/9.0);

       }
    }
 }
```

I just have one output issue with this program. The conversion from C to F is correct but from F to C is incorrect. The math formula is correct, but why the output isn't? please help... Thank you.

Michelle

Comment: What is your input and outputs? What do you expect as a result? What your program gives you as a result?

Comment: the output is three 3 options, 1 F covert to C, 2 C convert to F, 3 exit program. if enter anything out of these three options like 4, 5 or so on then it will alert user that this is an invalid input, and please try again.

Comment: The same ConvertCelcius is called in choice 1 and 2. Must be a spelling error.

Comment: OOOh, damn, been looking for this error all night, just couldnt find it... thank you so much

Comment: @Michelle: Please read up on how to debug your application, line by line. you would have found the problem much quicker that way, and without having to ask for help here. [Maybe this will help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ee672313.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling the wrong method:

```
        if (ichoice == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Celsius temperature: ");
            cTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            convertToF = **ConvertCelcius**(cTemp);
            Console.WriteLine(cTemp + "Celsius is " + convertToF+ "Fahrenheit");
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the temperature conversion application");
               Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________");
            GetChoice(ref ichoice);

        }
```

Comment: I won't vote you down, but I feel you could have put a bit more effort into this answer. It isn't explained very well, and the OP is obviously struggling with the basics

Comment: I don't think the OP is struggling with the basics at all, they just made a typo which they struggled to spot. What more could I have written to explain to them that they're calling the wrong method? Thanks for not voting me down :)

Comment: I would say not being able to debug this problem on their own is struggling with the basics... and you could have limited the code to showing the incorrect line and then shown the correct line instead. I mean it does the job, I just don't like it personally

Comment: Thank you guys, I spotted the error, I guess no more coding homework at night anymore... thank you :)

Comment: Hey it happens to the best of us, sometimes a little bit of sleep goes a long way.